# Inline-block breaking with padding

Tags: css

What I have is some categories and I have them set to inline-block.  I want them to break to the next line depending on the size of the screen, this works perfect when I have no padding set...but I also want to have a 10% padding on the left and right.  When I manually resize the screen the padding is causing the inline-block div to break more at the center of the div rather than the right edge, as you can see in the image....

https://photos.app.goo.gl/8f4eg88HbQMAgPnD6

Is there a way I can fix this?

EDIT

Sorry

```
.category-container {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color: #B37A1E;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.category {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #A2CBFA;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    verticle-align: center;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Category Container is the large orange div in the image and category is the smaller blue divs contained within the orange div.

Comment: Please provide code. That helps us help you.

Comment: Whithout a source code, you cannot get help.You can put it on jsfidle or plunker and provide a link.

Comment: @THEHOLYSPIRIT There should be no reason that the OP cannot post their [mcve] within a snippet in their question. Third party resources shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Sorry. To be clear, please edit your question and add the code there . Don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Original Post edited with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
.category-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%; // use max-width instead of width
    color: white;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color: #B37A1E;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it in the least.

Comment: It didn't, they don't break to the next line at all now.

Comment: @KevinLupo Okay i edited again. It should work now. Try and let me know.

Comment: PERFECT! That's exactly the way I want it to work.  I did have to add a height of 25px to my.category class, as it was making it expand the height of the .category-container class...but other then that, perfect!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your container.

Here's a [Pen](https://codepen.io/agustinrhcp/pen/orEdKQ)

Comment: That did not fix it either

Comment: I think I didn't save my last changes. But If does not what you were looking for I may have misunderstood your problem.